# Is there extension to show the models on a level?

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-bim360

I'd like to make a function to show models on a level which someone selected like a function that we can see in BIM 360 docs.

[level selection in BIM 360 docs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tFi5M.png)

Is there such kind of extension?

Answer (score 1):

Try the `Autodesk.AEC.LevelsExtension` extension - so long as the model comes with the required AEC data about existing floors:

```
viewer.addEventListener(Autodesk.Viewing.OBJECT_TREE_CREATED_EVENT/Autodesk.Viewing.GEOMETRY_LOADED_EVENT , //wait till design data is loaded
   viewer.loadExtension('Autodesk.AEC.LevelsExtension')
)
```

[image]

You can inspect whether your model contains the necessary data using `model.getAecModelData()`

Comment: Thank you for your replying. 
So there is no way to use the level object which is created in Revit...

I try to use this extension!